# How to run multiple simulators by COMMAND - Xcode 13 with no "instruments" anymore

Tags: xcode, macos, expo, ios-simulator, xcode13

These commands were used to run multiple simulators, install Expo, and run the app. This was working fine before Xcode 13, and after installing Xcode 13, it doesn't load simulators anymore as it can not find "instruments" anymore.

Any idea?

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a simulators=("0FAE2F92-9EF7-4C4A-8F9D-097A056F8CC0" "BFCDD662-E4DE-4C08-9DF6-CAACA7C00CEC" "1A6959A0-C10F-474B-96C5-7E8955FBDD80")

for i in "${simulators[@]}"
do
    xcrun instruments -w $i
    xcrun simctl install $i ~/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/Exponent-2.19.6.tar.app
    xcrun simctl openurl $i exp://127.0.0.1:19000      
done
```

Comment: Xcode from the App Store is supposedly broken. Xcode from developer site apparently okay. Which do you have?

Comment: @Magnas I have posted the answer here. Also, the solution you provided did not work since the "instruments" is not available on Xcode 13 anymore.

Comment: I didn’t provide a solution. I mentioned reports that developers were experiencing problems with the version of Xcode d/l from the AppStore and asked if you might have that version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those who need to run multiple simulators with one command, please follow this instruction. Since "instruments" is not available on Xcode 13 anymore, you need an equivalent command to boot simulators.

Replace the device IDs with your device IDs `xcrun simctl list`. Also, replace the Expo version with what you have on your machine.

```
#!/bin/zsh
declare -a simulators=("27D6B718-8348-4C4D-ADFC-6506C2A88EED" "531A59B8-6197-4620-904B-E55308D1EE96" "C08532FE-3CE4-4BB7-A04C-795F2FA7EFE1")
echo "STARTED"
open -a Simulator
wait_time=1
for i in $simulators[@]
do
    echo "Boot $i"
    xcrun simctl boot $i
    sleep $wait_time
    echo "Install Expo $i"
    xcrun simctl install $i ~/.expo/ios-simulator-app-cache/Exponent-2.19.6.tar.app
    sleep $wait_time
    echo "Lauch Expo $i"
    xcrun simctl openurl $i exp://127.0.0.1:19000
    sleep $wait_time
done
echo "FINISHED"
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that Fred A proposed works. "xcrun simctl" boot command can replace the instruments command to start the simulator. I can't find the exact xctrace command that replace the instruments -w command in those multiple simulators example, until finding some clue in this post. Thanks Fred A!

Below is the script I modified to start multiple simulators in Xcode 13.

```
# installs and lanches the `bundle_id` for the specified simulator device
### bin/sh

# please put the simulators UUID in this array

simulators=("B75B9F28-AE93-4B06-8110-AD284CB1DDB7" "A3101107-6605-4E92-A45B-20E3DDF25E37" )

# please put the app_location here

app_location_path="~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXXXX-cswzhnrhthwoqzdptzdcosamizis/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator"
app_name="XXXXXX.app"
bundle_id="XXXXX"


for i in ${simulators[@]}
do
        echo "xcrun simctl boot \"$i\""
        xcrun simctl boot "$i" &
        echo "xcrun simctl install \"$i\" $app_location_path/$app_name"
        xcrun simctl install "$i" $app_location_path/$app_anme &
        echo "xcrun simctl launch \"$i\" \"$bundle_id\""
        xcrun simctl launch "$i" "$bundle_id" &
done
```